# Inserting data from a field with decimal(39,9) to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I have linked server in SQL Server; when I tried to add a record to SQL Server and store a value into a column with datatype `decimal(38,0)` using

```
Cast(JrnlRow.Quantity as Decimal(38,0) as Quantity
```

I get the following error:

> "Column or parameter specified a column precision that is greater than the maximum precision of 38"

The data type (precision and scale) `decimal(39,19)` is invalid in SQL Server since the max decimal precision is 38. How can I convert `decimal(39,19)` to `decimal(38,0)` to insert record to a SQL Server column?

```
INSERT INTO DB1.dbo.WORKORDERS ([WORK ORDER #],[QUANTITY],[CUSTOMER],[SO DATE],[SO NUMBER],[ASSY PN-S],[CUSTOMER PN],[SHIP VIA],[PROMISED DATE],[COMMENTS],[PO #],[WO Notes])
    SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), next value for dbo.WorkOrderSequence),
        x.Quantity,--
        x.Customer_Bill_Name,
        x.TransactionDate,
        x.Reference,
        x.ItemID,
        x.PartNumber,
        x.WhichShipVia,
        x.ShipByDate,
        x.Comment2,
        x.CustomerInvoiceNo,
        x.SalesDescription
    FROM
        OPENQUERY ([db29], 'select distinct           
               Customers.Customer_Bill_Name,
               JrnlHdr.TransactionDate,
Cast(JrnlRow.Quantity as Decimal(38,0) as Quantity,
               JrnlHdr.Reference, 
               LineItem.ItemID ,
               LineItem.PartNumber, 
               Customers.WhichShipVia, 
               JrnlHdr.ShipByDate, 
               JrnlHdr.Comment2,
               JrnlHdr.CustomerInvoiceNo, 
               LineItem.SalesDescription    
        FROM   Customers
        INNER JOIN JrnlHdr
        ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = JrnlHdr.CustVendId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Address
        ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = Address.CustomerRecordNumber
        INNER JOIN JrnlRow
        ON JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder
        INNER JOIN LineItem 
        ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber
        WHERE  JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11 AND JrnlHdr.TransactionDate = CURDATE()-1 
        AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder  
        AND JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber 
        AND JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber 
        AND JrnlHdr.POSOisClosed = 0 ' 
        )  as x
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need that? Trying to store distance between galaxies in inches?

Comment: Please give examples of the values you are dealing with.

Comment: @juergend i cant set a decimal precision greater than 38 in sql server, 38 is the max where as Quantity field on the linked server precision  39,19

Comment: @juergend . . . The nearest galaxy is about 9.3 * 10^21 inches away.  This would support an accuracy considerably less than one nanometer -- less than the diameter of an atom.

Comment: @juergend i am trying to get the data from Sage accounting using linked server  software which is very closed application, that is how its setup, all work well except this Quantity field

Comment: As I see, you have a mistake "Cast(JrnlRow.Quantity as Decimal(38,0) as Quantity," check parenthesis here.

Comment: @AliaksandrBortnik Thank you ya, that was a mistake on he question i think i now figure it out i chnage the data type to decimal(38,0)  and used this on the statement ` Cast(JrnlRow.Quantity as Decimal(38,0)) as Quantity,` Thank you all for you time

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to truncate the last digit from the sequence.

For example, I have got a number 123456789012345678901234567890123456789 that I want to insert into a table. The number is 39 digits long. Using the left function I can loose the last digit.

```
select cast(left('1234567890123456789012345678901234567890',38) as numeric(38,0))
```